# Loop through XML tags with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, loops, xpath

I have an XML which has the following content:

```
<ruletypes>
 <ruletype>Local</ruletype>
 <ruletype>Global</ruletype>
 ...
</ruletypes>
```

I'm wanting a list of the ruletypes, I tried the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ruletypes/ruletype">
 <li><xsl:value-of select="ruletype"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the select like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//ruletypes/ruletype">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: To clarify, `xsl:for-each` sets the context to the `ruletype` element that is selected, so the OP's `select="ruletype"` looks for *another* `ruletype` *under* that element (and there are none).  This way, the current `ruletype` element is selected (`.`) and converted to a string, which will return the node's text value.

Answer (score 3):

Eschew `for-each` and let the XSLT processor do most of the work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="ruletype">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this document:

```
<ruletypes>
   <ruletype>Local</ruletype>
   <ruletype>Global</ruletype>
</ruletypes>
```

Produces the following output:

```
<li>Local</li>
<li>Global</li>
```

Note that this takes advantage of XSLT's [built-in template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) for elements, which keeps the processing moving until an "interesting" node is encountered, and its built-in template for text nodes, which copies text through.